# Google Glass tech to improve a Manufacturing Process?

Tags: google-glass, business-intelligence

At a semiconductor chip-making facility, many machines and many hands and robots are used to produce and test wafers and chips during the very long process. It seems to me that Google Glass could be productively used for that.

I am a total Google Glass newbie, I'm  brainstorming whether it might be a good tech.

Is Glass capable of receiving data from a machine and displaying it as a visual overlay? Would I have to do that by software from the vendor or could it read things by plugging into (a hardware attachment?)?

I'm  sure Glass can read anything on the web or a database to which the wearer has login privileges, right? So then it's just a matter of applying a nice "GUI" which is transluscent in this case?

Can Glasses talk to each other directly?

thank you so much!

p.s. My apologies if this post violates a rule of etiquette. If you think it does, my questions to you are (if relevant to your feedback);

1.Which StackExchange site would be correct? The https://startups.stackexchange.com/ is 99% focused on business logistics. This is a tech question: what is feasible?

2.Alot of times "Best x" posts appear to be highly cited/up-voted yet closed/deleted. I honestly do not understand that. Is there a better way to pose the question? I think as long as a specific use case is given then this is a good forum, because it's an architectural software choice and tech input is required? So the 'best' 'most objective' answer would be one that justifies its response well on principles of SOLID, Immutability, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is Glass capable of receiving data from a machine and displaying it as a visual overlay? Would I have to do that by software from the vendor or could it read things by plugging into (a hardware attachment?)?

I'm sure Glass can read anything on the web or a database to which the wearer has login privileges, right? So then it's just a matter of applying a nice "GUI" which is transluscent in this case?

Can Glasses talk to each other directly?"

Yes, Glass is capable of receiving data from a machine and displaying it in a visual overlay. You'd probably want to have that done through a server that would store the data, and then you would just pull the data from that server. I'm not quite sure of a way to do it through connection. I think it would be much smoother to just push data to a server from the machine, and then pull that data onto the Glass.

Yeah, if I understand the problem correctly, it should be as simple as pulling the data and placing it onto a nice GUI. An even cooler idea could be to have each machine have its own tag that could be scanned by the Glass, which would pull up the information automatically, no commands necessary (except pressing the "Camera" button to grab a picture and get the tag image.

Finally, yes, I think that Glass has the capability of communicating with other Glass, but nor very simply, and I haven't seen it done or done it myself. I'm not sure how you'd want them to communicate. Again, I think that aspect would be infinitely easier through a server - communicate from the Glass to a server to another Glass.

I hope that helped. Best of luck :)

Comment: thank you @Alex K! Yes , that helps alot! I come from a background of trying to conserve round trips but especially in a manufacturing zone if the server is local your idea of having a middleman server seems very good.

Comment: This may also be interesting to you: http://www.bostonglobe.com/business/2014/06/14/google-glass-moves-into-hospital-beth-israel-deaconess/VQNGKK9842vbRIzlM2201J/story.html                               Here is a quote from the article: Beth Israel has integrated Google Glass by posting a unique QR code, something like a barcode, on the doorway to each emergency patient’s room. Special software installed on hospital versions of the glasses can read the code and instantly call up a patient’s electronic medical record." That iswhat I was talking about with have a "tag" (qr code) on the machines.